# set keypad of iphone in portrait mode when status bar is in landscape mode in Objective C

Tags: iphone

My application is in landscape mode only . On login screen i rotated view forcefully by Affine transform. how i can rotate or set keypad and alert view orientation as portrait mode when status bar is in landscape mode in Objective C